# eas cli update is not working for my expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm using eas cli for my app and I tried to update my app with eas cli but It is not totally working I used to use expo publish but suddenly It's changed I have no idea what i changed

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.7.0",
    "promptToConfigurePushNotifications": false
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "store",
      "releaseChannel": "default",
      "channel": "default"
    },
    "preview": {
      "releaseChannel": "default",
      "ios": {
        "autoIncrement": "buildNumber"
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle"
      },
      "channel": "default",
      "distribution": "store"
    },
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "channel": "default",
      "releaseChannel": "default"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "track": "production",
      },
      "ios": {
        "companyName": "턴백",
        "appName": "턴백",
        "language": "kr"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ],
    "scheme": "turnbag",
    "name": "턴백",
    "slug": "turnbag-native-app",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "description": "턴백",
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "sdkVersion"
    },
    "originalFullName": "@turnbag/turnbag-native-app",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./assets/badge.png",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "mode": "production"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "Turnbag이 갤러리에 접근할 수 있도록 권한을 허락해 주세요"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-tracking-transparency",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": "Turnbag이 데이터에 접근할 수 있도록 권한을 허락해 주세요"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#680707"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0,
      "url": "..."
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "usesAppleSignIn": true,
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "bundleIdentifier": "kr.co.turnbag",
      "buildNumber": "2.0.2",
      "associatedDomains": [
        "turnbag://turnbag.co.kr"
      ],
      "infoPlist": {
        "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes": [
          "kftc-bankpay",
          "ispmobile",
          "itms-apps",
          "hdcardappcardansimclick",
          "smhyundaiansimclick",
          "shinhan-sr-ansimclick",
          "smshinhanansimclick",
          "kb-acp",
          "mpocket.online.ansimclick",
          "ansimclickscard",
          "ansimclickipcollect",
          "vguardstart",
          "samsungpay",
          "scardcertiapp",
          "lottesmartpay",
          "lotteappcard",
          "cloudpay",
          "nhappcardansimclick",
          "nonghyupcardansimclick",
          "citispay",
          "citicardappkr",
          "citimobileapp",
          "kakaotalk",
          "payco",
          "chaipayment",
          "kb-auth",
          "hyundaicardappcardid",
          "com.wooricard.wcard",
          "lmslpay",
          "lguthepay-xpay",
          "liivbank",
          "supertoss"
        ],
        "NSAppTransportSecurity": {
          "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": true,
          "NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent": true
        },
        "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": "Turnbag이 데이터에 접근할 수 있도록 권한을 허락해 주세요",
        "SKAdNetworkItems": [
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "..."
          },
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "..."
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "package": "kr.co.turnbag",
      "versionCode": 10,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "category": [
            "DEFAULT",
            "BROWSABLE"
          ],
          "data": {
            "scheme": "turnbag"
          }
        }
      ],
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
      ]
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "turnbag-native-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@actbase/react-daum-postcode": "^1.0.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.7",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.3",
    "axios": "0.24.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "expo": "45.0.8",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~4.2.1",
    "expo-application": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.6.1",
    "expo-crypto": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.0.1",
    "expo-device": "~4.2.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.3.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.15.4",
    "expo-random": "~12.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-tracking-transparency": "~2.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.2.1",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "iamport-react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "polished": "^4.2.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-easing-gradient": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "10.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.18.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "eas-cli": "^2.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and I built my app with default channel for android, ios
My eas channel is linked default branch now
and My app builds are linked default channel now